# Function pointer with & and without

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

What is the difference between :

```
int (*wskNaF)(int, int) = addition;
```

and this line

```
int (*wskNaF)(int, int) = &addition;
```

score is exactly the same:

```
#include <cstdio>

int addition( int a, int b );

int (*wskNaF)(int, int) = addition;
//int (*wskNaF)(int, int) = &addition;

int main()
{
  printf("Score= %d\n", wskNaF(5,7));
  return 0;
}

int addition( int a, int b )
{
  return a + b;
}
// g++ test.cpp -o test && ./test
```

I supposed that function name is also her pointer? Am I wrong?

Comment: The function name can *decay* into a pointer to the function.